# jrecord to convert cobol data files to csv with S3 file system

Tags: python, csv, cobol, jrecord

We have been using JRecord library to read Cobol data files and convert them to csv files by passing copybooks as input arguments. That works fine with command like below

```
java -jar Cobol2Csv.jar -C sample.cpy -Delimiter \u007c -Q SingleQuote -Rename 0 -IFS Fixed_Length -IC cp037 -OC cp1252 -I SampleInput.dat -O SampleOutput.csv
```

Now, we have moved our input cobol data files to S3, So is there a way to use **JRecord** with S3 file system?

Also is it possible to convert cobol data files to csv in python in any other way?

Comment: Seems unlikely. You might investigate [mounting S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/mountpoint-amazon-s3/).